# undefined method in text_field while column exists

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a form that is going to be used, but i run into this problem when opening the form:

```
NoMethodError in Measures#new

Showing /home/supervisor/Rubyrails/Werkvergunning/app/views/measures/_form.html.erb where line #22 raised:

undefined method `measurement_type' for #<Measure:0x007f7bb3c5f978>
Did you mean?  measurement
               measurement?
               measurement=
               measurement_was
```

I am absolutely positive that the field exists and other fields from the same table used to work without problem, so it is just thos one field. 
What is going on and how can i fix it?
The _form:

```
<%= form_for(@measure) do |f| %>
  <% if @measure.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@measure.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this measure from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @measure.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :measurement %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :measurement %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type %><br>
    <%# f.select :measurement_type, [['Product verklaring','product vrij verklaring'],['Elektrotechnische maatregel','Elektrotechnische maatregelen'],['Maatregel door vergunninghouder','maatregel door vergunninghouder'], ['brandpreventie', 'brandpreventie'], ['persoonnlijke bescherming', 'persoonlijke bescherming']] %>
    <%= f.text_field :measurement_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :valid_from %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :valid_from %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :valid_to %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :valid_to %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :enquiry_measure_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :enquiry_measure_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The table:

```
create_table "measures", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "measurement",        limit: 255
    t.string  "measurement_type",   limit: 255
    t.date    "valid_from"
    t.date    "valid_to"
    t.integer "enquiry_measure_id", limit: 4
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: could you show the controller?

Comment: Try restarting your app.

Comment: Didn't think it would, but a restart helped me out. Thanks